# Warning after importing Python library into Eclipe

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x

Using Eclipse I have been learning Python and want to import 'pdfminer' into my program.

I used the 'File'>'Import'>'General'>'File System' and have the following directory structure in my project:

```
src >
    pdf_parser.py # My program
    pdfminer # Folder contains all pdfminer .py files
        pdfinterp.py # includes PDFResourceManager & process_pdf modules
```

The 'pdf_parser.py' is my program and I import using :

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is wrong? what is the error message? try also editing your post as it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, and I am not sure if this is 'Pythonic' but it is possible to do this using :

```
pdfminer.pdfinterp.PDFResourceManager as PDFResourceManager
```

instead of :

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
```

Both Eclipse and Python3 were happy with this solution, and it allowed me to import the modules from sub-directories within my programs directory.